# Transpose nested data structures

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, functor, fold

I need a function like `Vector [Vector a] -> Vector [Vector a]`, where everything stays within the same list-index, but (for each list-index) the i-th element of the j-th inner-vector becomes the j-th element of the i-th inner-vector. **I suspect I'm making this a lot harder than it needs to be.**

I think I specifically want to use [this implementation of fixed-length vectors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vec-0.4/docs/Data-Vec-Lazy.html), but I could consider other options.

I have it working on a stand-in `Pair` class I wrote for simplicity, but my implementation relies heavily on pattern-matching against the structure of `Pair`, in a way that I think won't work for a `Vec n`.

The `Pair` class is barely relevant; it's similar to `Vec nat2`, but I only implemented what I thought I'd need:

```hs
data Pair a where
  Pair :: a -> a -> Pair a
  deriving (Read, Show, Eq)
instance Functor Pair where
  fmap f (Pair a1 a2) = Pair (f a1) (f a2)
instance Applicative Pair where
  pure a = Pair a a
  (Pair f1 f2) <*> (Pair a1 a2) = Pair (f1 a1) (f2 a2)
instance Foldable Pair where
  foldr f b (Pair a1 a2) = a1 `f` (a2 `f` b)

(!) :: Pair a -> Bool -> a
(Pair a1 a2) ! b = if b then a2 else a1

universe :: Pair Bool
universe = Pair False True
```

#### Working code:

```hs
transpose :: Pair [Pair a] -> Pair [Pair a]
transpose (Pair b1s b2s) = t' b1s b2s
  where t' ((Pair a11 a12) : a1s) ((Pair a21 a22) : a2s)
            = Pair ((Pair a11 a21) :) ((Pair a12 a22) :) <*> t' a1s a2s
        t' [] [] = pure []
        -- A runtime error here is ok; I have external guarantees that this won't happen.
        t' _ _ = error "Transposition requires the lists to be of equal length."
```

#### Example:

```hs
> let subject = Pair [
      Pair (1, 1, 1) (1, 1, 2),
      Pair (1, 2, 1) (1, 2, 2),
      Pair (1, 3, 1) (1, 3, 2)
  ] [
      Pair (2, 1, 1) (2, 1, 2),
      Pair (2, 2, 1) (2, 2, 2),
      Pair (2, 3, 1) (2, 3, 2)
  ]
> transpose subject
↠ Pair [
      Pair (1,1,1) (2,1,1),
      Pair (1,2,1) (2,2,1),
      Pair (1,3,1) (2,3,1)
  ] [
      Pair (1,1,2) (2,1,2),
      Pair (1,2,2) (2,2,2),
      Pair (1,3,2) (2,3,2)
  ]
```

With some struggle I can *almost* get an implementation that exclusively uses list/functor/applicative/index-able operators instead of pattern matching (and should therefore work for a `Vec n`), but I keep getting stuck.

**How can I re-write my `transpose` function to work on some other structure *like* `Pair`, but with parametric size?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd use `ZipList` and a new, analogous `ZipVector` to achieve this. We'll start with a more standard `transpose`:

```
transposeVV :: Vector (Vector a) -> Vector (Vector a)
transposeVV = getZipVector . traverse Finite
```

To be able to use this, we'll need to be able to put the two `Vector`'s next to each other; we'll do this via two more transposes that are inverses of each other:

```
transposeVL :: Vector [a] -> [Vector a]
transposeVL = getZipList . traverse ZipList

transposeLV :: [Vector a] -> Vector [a]
transposeLV = getZipVector . traverse Finite
```

The thing you want is now a conjugation of these:

```
transposeVlV :: Vector [Vector a] -> Vector [Vector a]
transposeVlV = transposeLV . fmap transposeVV . transposeVL
```

Okay, well, I hid some of the functionality away behind `ZipVector`. What does that look like? It's easy enough; however, one twist compared to `ZipList` is that we can't easily construct an infinite vector. No big deal, we'll fake it. (Your length-indexed vectors won't need to pull this trick, obviously.)

```
data ZipVector a
    = Inf a
    | Finite (Vector a)
    deriving Functor

getZipVector :: ZipVector a -> Vector a
getZipVector (Inf a) = V.singleton a -- hmmmm...
getZipVector (Finite as) = as

instance Applicative ZipVector where
    pure = Inf
    Inf f <*> Inf x = Inf (f x)
    Inf f <*> Finite xs = Finite (f <$> xs)
    Finite fs <*> Inf x = Finite (($x) <$> fs)
    Finite fs <*> Finite xs = Finite (V.zipWith ($) fs xs)
```

We can try it out now. First let's define your `subject`:

```
subject :: Vector [Vector (Int, Int, Int)]
subject =
    V.generate 2 $ \i ->
        flip map [0..2] $ \j ->
            V.generate 2 $ \k ->
                (i+1, j+1, k+1)
```

Then, in ghci:

```
> transposeVlV subject
[[[(1,1,1),(2,1,1)],[(1,2,1),(2,2,1)],[(1,3,1),(2,3,1)]],[[(1,1,2),(2,1,2)],[(1,2,2),(2,2,2)],[(1,3,2),(2,3,2)]]]
```

Comment: This appears to be a translation of the signature (if not the implementation) of [Data.List.Transpose](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) to use [Data.Vector.Vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.3.0/docs/Data-Vector.html). Leaving aside that I _do_ want type-level specification of length for the inner and outer dimensions, this answer doesn't address the middle-dimension of `List`. (I _also_ need a solution that's lazy w/r/to the middle list dimension. Maybe this really is hard...)

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter Thanks. You're right, I read the question too quickly. I've updated my answer. I've used non-length-indexed vectors for simplicity of exposition, but I don't think the ideas here should be too hard to adapt if you really do need that.

Comment: Is `transposeLV` just `distribute`?

Comment: @dfeuer For fixed-size vectors, possibly yes. But "just" is an odd modifier there; after all, one must still implement `distribute`.

Comment: @dfeuer, do you mean [this `distribute`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html#v:distribute)? 'cause `Data.Vec.Lazy.Vec` already has [an instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vec-0.4/docs/Data-Vec-Lazy.html#t:Vec) :)

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter, yes, that one.

Comment: @DanielWagner, yes, but it's already there in this case.

Comment: This works! It's even lazy enough, which surprised me. Since `Vec n` already has all the needed instances, this can actually be quite concise. For completeness I'll eventually post my own version here, after some code review.